# Unpivot in Potgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

How can I unpivot in Postgresql without using UNION? I have more than 100 columns, and I am looking for a neat way to do it.

Given table:

```
id    c1      c2      c3
1      X       Y       Z
2      A       B       C
3      Y       C       Z
```

Desired table:

```
id   col
1     X
1     Y
1     Z
2     A
2     B
2     C
3     Y
3     C
3     Z
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [jsonb functions:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select id, value as col
from my_table
cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(my_table))
where key <> 'id';

 id | value 
----+-------
  1 | X
  1 | Y
  1 | Z
  2 | A
  2 | B
  2 | C
  3 | Y
  3 | C
  3 | Z
(9 rows)
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3908c34454bc5d2d4d1b2b0e0a8356b1)

---

In Postgres 9.3 or 9.4 use `to_json()` and `json_each_text()`.

In versions 9.1 or 9.2 install [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html):

```
create extension if not exists hstore;

select id, value as col
from my_table
cross join each(hstore(my_table))
where key <> 'id';
```

Comment: Thank you @klin. I am getting the following error: function to_jsonb(my_table) does not exist. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The function is available in Postgres 9.5+; if you have version 9.3 or 9.4 use `json_each_text()` and `to_json()`.

Comment: Thanks but getting the same error. Can it be that my postgres installation missing something?

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: It is 9.2. Probably that's why!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, in 9.2 json type support is residual. Upgrade! ;)

Comment: Oops! :)  Thanks. Marked as right answer. I am pretty sure this is the correct answer if I had the correct version! :)

Comment: It seems I should either upgrade or use UNION! :) hstore didn't work either. throwing: function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level... it complains about "my_table" in hstore(my_table).